# Nodejs Microsoft Upload File to a Sharepoint file storage API

Tags: node.js, axios, microsoft-graph-api

Hey i am trying to upload a file to a sharepoint file storage for that i want to find out
all available sites and their id.

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = async function getSiteIds(logger, accessToken) {
    const graphEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*';
    const headers = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.get(graphEndpoint, { headers });
        const siteIds = response.data.value.map(function(site) {
            return site.id;
        });
        return siteIds;
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error getting site IDs:', error.message);


        throw error;
    }
}
```

when i am doing this i get an error:

```
'AccessDenied',
message: 'Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.',
```

i am generating a token with scope '.default'

I was execting a list of all sharepoint sites.
My application has all needed permissions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: 'your_client_id',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenant_id',
    
  }
};

const request = {
  scopes: ['Sites.Read.All', 'Sites.ReadWrite.All']
};

const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

async function getSiteIds(logger) {
  try {
    const loginResponse = await myMSALObj.loginPopup(request);
    const accessToken = loginResponse.accessToken;

    const graphEndpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*';
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    };

    const response = await axios.get(graphEndpoint, { headers });
    const siteIds = response.data.value.map(site => site.id);
    return siteIds;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Error getting site IDs:', error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}

module.exports = getSiteIds;
```